# Inject css to page without using onload (IE)?

Tags: javascript

I've written a widget which relies on having to inject a css file onto the html page.

I am using the following code to inject the css-sheet:

```
                var link = document.createElement("link");
                link.href = "http://myurl.com/style.css";
                link.rel = "stylesheet";
                document.body.appendChild(link);
```

This works in all browsers except for IE, for this to work in IE i have to do a:

> window.onload

Like this:

```
window.onload=function() {
    //inject here
}
```

I want to find a way to accomplish this without having to use window.onload, since window.onload only loads my widget when all of the pages has loaded, for bigger pages it takes forever to load the widget.. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the this script is in the body. Append it to the head and not the body

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(link);
```

Comment: What would happend if the target page does not have a head tag? (I know this is rare but it _can_ happend) :)

Comment: What page does not have a head? That is where styles should live.

Comment: @Alosyius Some pages use `<frameset>` instead of `<body>`. Anything can happen.

Comment: @epascarello Technically, they **could not**. My point is that too many setups are possible and it's silly to expect an answer to cover anything (I'm defending your answer as correct). This is also before Aloysius edited their original comment

Comment: You could also inject it on dom ready. And if you are really afraid there will be no head than add a check and add a fallback.